# How to store User name and password details in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am developing an app, it has a login page. I need to store the login credentials. Can it be in my strings.xml file? Because I have heard that `Strings.xml` can not be modified at run time. So where can I store data i.e. User details or application details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Shared Preferences**. Like so:

Create these methods for use, or just use the content inside of the methods whenever you want:

```
public String getUserName()
{
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("userNameAndPassword", 0);
  String str = sp.getString("userName","no userName created");
  return str;
}

public String getPassword()
{
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("userNameAndPassword", 0);
  String str = sp.getString("password","no password created");
  return str;
}

public void writeToUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String password)
{
  SharedPreferences.Editor pref = 
                           getSharedPreferences("userNameAndPassword",0).edit();
  pref.putString("userName", userName);
  pref.putString("password", password);
  pref.commit();
}
```

You could call them like this:

```
// their userName if "foo" and their password is "bar"
writeToUserNameAndPassword("foo", "bar");

if (getUserName().equals(inputUserName) && getPassword.equals(inputPassword))
{
   // they have the right userName and password
}
else if (getUserName().equals("no userName created")
         && getPassword().equals("no password created"))
{
   // these preference Strings for their userName/password have both not been created
}
else if (getUserName().equals("no userName created"))
{
   // this preference String for their userName has not been created, 
   // but the password has been
}
else if (getPassword().equals("no password created"))
{
   // this preference String for their password has not been created, 
   // but the userName has been
}
else
{
   // they entered the wrong userName and/or password
}
```

**Some explanation** (if needed):

`"password"` and `"userName"` are the 'key' `Strings` in the preference. So you reference those keys to obtain the `String` you put in there. It is a reference name for the `String` you put.

`"userNameAndPassword"` is the *preference name*. You use the preference name, "userNameAndPassword", to reference the preference you want to access.

`"no password created"` and `"no userName created"` are the `Strings` that the `getString` method will return if the preference doesn't have a `String` referenced to by `"password"` or `"userName"`, meaning that it hasn't been created.

Another way to put it: they are the default values of the reference `String`. So if nothing has been put their instead, the method will return the default values. You have to set the default values.

So, for example, if no "password" `String` has been put into the `"userNameAndPassword"` preference (written to using `putString`), then the `getPassword()` method will return `"no password created"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can store login information in **SharedPreference** or **SqliteDatabase**.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", YOUR_USERNAME);
        editor.putString("password", YOUR_PASSWORD);
        editor.commit();
```

**For retrieving Login information**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String username = prefs.getString("username", null);
String password = prefs.getString("password", null);
```

If you need more security you can use **SQLCipher** using **SqliteDatabase**

Please go through [this](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) link.

Comment: Can u give any example

Comment: in which file these values will stored

Answer (score 0):

In simple words **YOU CAN'T STORE OR CHANGE** the content of *strings.xml*

But yes as User @amit said you can 
store these values in Shared Preferences

Or You can Use **SQLite Database** to store what ever you want [learn sqlite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

For example

### for setting the Value

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefEditor.putInt(LAUNCH_COUNT, 1); // you can have multiple put (values)
prefEditor.commit();
prefEditor.apply();
```

### For getting the value

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int launchCount = sp.getInt(LAUNCH_COUNT, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Armit mentioned before, you can store the data in the SharedPreferences. Just be aware that this gets stored in a simple XML file that can be seen and modified with an editor. You should at least encrypt it or, better, not save it at all. Usually, you log in to a server or site and then save only the return token. You only use the token to connect again and you don't have to save the password in plain text.